# how to make button small show 7 button horizontally

Tags: android

I am creating a calendar like this  image 
[image]

but my screen will look like this

[image]

how i is not fully s how all 7 buttons is only show 4 buttons how i will make layout same like sample image

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/last_week"
     android:layout_width="50sp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#F2F2F2"
     android:src="@drawable/barrowleft2" >
  </ImageView>

  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6" >

    <TableRow
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sun"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sunday"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/monday"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tuesday"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/wednesday"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thur"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/thursday"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fri"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/friday"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/saturday"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/e06"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
        </Button>
     </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>

  <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/next_week"
     android:layout_width="50sp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#F2F2F2"
     android:src="@drawable/barrrow113" >
  </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why use android:layout_weight="1" on the tablelayout ?

Comment: try using gridlayout with single row or linearlayout with weights

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try like following code..however it is not right way to implement calender..You should use GridView

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/e06"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/calendar_button_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#D9DBD7" >
</Button>
```

Comment: where i set layout weight? in lenearlayout weight 7? and then add wweight 1 for each button?

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need to use `Button` for your buttons. I'd use `TextView` apply all layout settings as I need set its `android:clickable` to `true` and treat as regular button. Will work and the benefit is that if will look as you like regardless of android version your app is running on (as `Button` looks different on 2.x and 3.x+)

Comment: give me example please